# Can we have an app_code folder in a console application?

Tags: app-code

I was wondering how to add an app_code folder in console application but could not find that, however I was able to add app_code folder to a website application. Sorry I am newbie don't know much?

Answer (score 0):

app_code folder is in use for ASP.Net Application there is no use of the folder in console application. Could you please explain it clearly why you want to use the folder? For more details you can see link given below.

http://www.bayt.com/en/specialties/q/937/why-do-you-use-the-app_code-folder-in-asp-net/

Comment: Even I am facing same problem. I need to store and read bunch of files in application.which is possible, in debug mode. But After publishing console Application, App_code folder is missing. Even after adding the folder explicitly, program doesn't referring it.